# Passing window and texture to a function

Tags: function, sfml

I started writing tile based game in SFML and ran into this problem.I think I am doing something wrong in passing the texture and window to a function.Please , help me ;) .And sorry for my english.

code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

class Tile
{

int number,colision;
Sprite sTile;
public:

//void add(int n,int c,Texture &tTile,int x,int y,int x2,int y2)   {number=n;colision=c;sTile.setTexture(&tTile);sTile.setTextureRect(IntRect(x,y,x2,y2));}     
int getcolision(){return colision;}
int getnumber(){return number;}
void drawTile(int x,int y,RenderWindow &window){sTile.setPosition(x,y);window.draw(sTile);}


};

int g_map[200][200];


int main()
{   for(int x=0;x<200;x++){for(int y=0;y<200;y++){g_map[x][y]=0;}}

RenderWindow window( VideoMode( 800, 600 ), "SFML2.1-window" );

Tile tile[100];
Texture tTile;
tTile.loadFromFile("textures.bmp");
tile[0].drawTile(0,0,window);

while( window.isOpen() )
{
    Event event;
    while( window.pollEvent( event ) )
    {
        if( event.type == Event::Closed )
             window.close();

    } //while
    window.clear();


    window.display();
} //while
return 0;
}
```

Errors:
C:\Users\Maks\AppData\Local\Temp\ccoLih4f.o SFMLproj.cpp:(.text+0x136): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf6StringC1EPKcRKSt6locale'
C:\Users\Maks\AppData\Local\Temp\ccoLih4f.o SFMLproj.cpp:(.text+0x15c): undefined reference to`*imp***ZN2sf9VideoModeC1Ejjj'
C:\Users\Maks\AppData\Local\Temp\ccoLih4f.o SFMLproj.cpp:(.text+0x1a0): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf12RenderWindowC1ENS_9VideoModeERKNS_6StringEjRKNS_15ContextSettingsE'
C:\Users\Maks\AppData\Local\Temp\ccoLih4f.o SFMLproj.cpp:(.text+0x1ed): undefined reference to`_imp**_ZN2sf7TextureC1Ev'
C:\Users\Maks\AppData\Local\Temp\ccoLih4f.o SFMLproj.cpp:(.text+0x238): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf7Texture12loadFromFileERKSsRKNS_4RectIiEE'
C:\Users\Maks\AppData\Local\Temp\ccoLih4f.o SFMLproj.cpp:(.text+0x293): undefined reference to`*imp***ZN2sf6Window5closeEv'
C:\Users\Maks\AppData\Local\Temp\ccoLih4f.o SFMLproj.cpp:(.text+0x2ab): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf6Window9pollEventERNS_5EventE'
C:\Users\Maks\AppData\Local\Temp\ccoLih4f.o SFMLproj.cpp:(.text+0x2dd): undefined reference to`_imp**_ZN2sf5ColorC1Ehhhh'
C:\Users\Maks\AppData\Local\Temp\ccoLih4f.o SFMLproj.cpp:(.text+0x2f8): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf12RenderTarget5clearERKNS_5ColorE'
C:\Users\Maks\AppData\Local\Temp\ccoLih4f.o SFMLproj.cpp:(.text+0x30a): undefined reference to`*imp***ZN2sf6Window7displayEv'
C:\Users\Maks\AppData\Local\Temp\ccoLih4f.o SFMLproj.cpp:(.text+0x319): undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK2sf6Window6isOpenEv'
C:\Users\Maks\AppData\Local\Temp\ccoLih4f.o SFMLproj.cpp:(.text+0x335): undefined reference to`_imp**_ZN2sf7TextureD1Ev'
C:\Users\Maks\AppData\Local\Temp\ccoLih4f.o SFMLproj.cpp:(.text+0x369): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf12RenderWindowD1Ev'
C:\Users\Maks\AppData\Local\Temp\ccoLih4f.o SFMLproj.cpp:(.text+0x393): undefined reference to`*imp***ZN2sf12RenderWindowD1Ev'
C:\Users\Maks\AppData\Local\Temp\ccoLih4f.o SFMLproj.cpp:(.text+0x421): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf7TextureD1Ev'
C:\Users\Maks\AppData\Local\Temp\ccoLih4f.o SFMLproj.cpp:(.text+0x461): undefined reference to`_imp**_ZN2sf12RenderWindowD1Ev'
C:\Users\Maks\AppData\Local\Temp\ccoLih4f.o SFMLproj.cpp:(.text$*ZN2sf8DrawableD2Ev[*_ZN2sf8DrawableD2Ev]+0xfffff6d2): undefined reference to `_imp___ZTVN2sf8DrawableE'
c:\dev-cpp\mingw32\mingw32\bin\ld.exe   C:\Users\Maks\AppData\Local\Temp\ccoLih4f.o: bad reloc address 0xe in section`.text$*ZN2sf8DrawableD2Ev[*_ZN2sf8DrawableD2Ev]'
c:\dev-cpp\mingw32\mingw32\bin\ld.exe   final link failed: Invalid operation
C:\Users\Maks\Documents\dev\sfml\Nowy folder (2)\tile\collect2.exe  [Error] ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you did not provide good linker settings, that are needed to link your executable with the SFML's DLLs.

Follow this [tutorial](http://sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/start-cb.php) attentively.

Comment: Oh , I just reloaded the file and now it works just fine.Thanks! :D